# failed to Cross compile Qt 5.6 on RPi 2 (fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory)

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi2, qt5.6

I try to cross compile Qt 5.6 for RPi 2 by following this tutorial https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS but I got this error

```
qeglfsbrcmintegration.cpp:35:22: fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bcm_host.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make[6]: *** [.obj/qeglfsbrcmintegration.o] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_brcm'
make[5]: *** [sub-eglfs_brcm-make_first] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration'
make[4]: *** [sub-deviceintegration-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[3]: *** [sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
make[2]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins'
make[1]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hamed/raspi/qtbase/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Similar question has been asked before here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/fatal-error-bcm-host-h-no-such-file-or-directory-compilation-terminated (solution inside).

Comment: Solution posted here, it works https://forum.qt.io/topic/62264/failed-to-cross-compile-qt-5-6-on-rpi-2-fatal-error-bcm_host-h-no-such-file-or-directory/4, you need two $ signs as specified in the last post of this forum link

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates one of two problems. Either:

1. The file `bcm_host.h` does not exist on your system, or:
2. The file exists, but the compiler can't find it.

To see whether the file exists, you can run:

```
$ find / -name bcm_host.h 2>/dev/null
```

If `bcm_host.h` doesn't exist, you need to fix that situation somehow. [This post](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/issues/78) suggests installing `libraspberrypi-dev`.

Once `bcm_host.h` exists on your system, you need to make sure the compiler can find it. [This post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) mentions that it may be necessary to create a symlink to wherever the build system is looking for include files. To see what the default include path is, you can run:

```
$ echo | cpp -Wp,-v
```

Then make your symlink accordingly. Or, you can try invoking `make` this way:

```
$ CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/bcm_host.h make
```

Comment: I have the files in my host Linux at  

`/home/hamed/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/include/`  

but compiler cant find the files  

I try use CPPFLAGS arg but it dos not works  

`make CPPFLAGS=I/home/hamed/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/include/bcm_host.h`  

`qeglfsbrcmintegration.cpp:35:22: fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or    directory
`

Comment: it dose't work again  CPPFLAGS=-I/home/hamed/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/include/bcm_host.h make

Comment: I think I should change eglfs library makefile to include the missing files but I don't know how !?

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` should contain _paths_, not files, so try: `CPPFLAGS=-I/home/hamed/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/include`. Or just run `$ sudo ln -s /usr /opt/vc` in a terminal as suggested in the linked post.

Answer (score 1):

In your .pro file (project file) add :

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/hamed/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/include
```

and then recompile.

if it doesn't work, remove the build folder and then recompile.

Answer (score 1):

add in this file: ~/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_brcm/eglfs_brcm.pro

```
INCLUDEPATH += ~/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/include
```

after :

```
$ make
```

and

```
make install
```